# Can endomorphisms be solely epis or monos

Tags: category-theory

Is the category of $Set$ and $Rel$ it holds, that if a function is an endomorphism it is either a bimorphism (epi + mono) or it is neither an epi or a mono.

Can this be an statement made about all categories in general?

Comment: No$\phantom{}\phantom{}$

Comment: In the category of fields, every morphism is monic, but there are endomorphisms which aren't epic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your statement is false even in $Set$ in $Rel$.  It is true for finite sets, but not for infinite sets, since you can have an injection from an infinite set to itself which is not a surjection or a surjection from an infinite set to itself which is not an injection.  For instance, $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ defined by $f(x)=x+1$ is injective but not surjective and $g:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ defined by $g(x)=\max(0,x-1)$ is surjective but not injective.